# VMware Workstation 10 running slow WinXP Pro SP3 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, memory, vmware-workstation

Just recently jumped onto the VMware bandwagon.
Going to be using it mostly for games, especially old ones that don't run well on my host Win7 Ult.Ed 64-bit.

I've setup everything and everything seems to be working well.

My main problem stems from the fact that I'm not really sure what the Memory portion of the VMware Setup means, is this the Memory WinXp will use or VMware?

I built my PC with 32GB RAM and have set the Slider in VMware to only 4096MB, is this fine? I assumed 32-bit windows would only see 4GB so that influenced my choice. Should I have set the Memory higher? as I do not know if this slider is for the OS or VMware.

I graduated from VMware Player where I had set Memory to 3GB and I could have sworn things were opening and installing faster than it is in Workstation, The only things I increased were Cores 1 > 2, Memory 3GB > 4GB and HDD space 50GB > 100GB

Also I had VMware Player running on an internal SATA 3Gb/s connected Hard Disk Drive versus Workstation on a USB 3.0 external Drive, that clearly has more free space than the internal.

Answer (score 1):

Check your bios and see if the Hardware Virtualization is enabled.
for any machine you made right click on it and go to settings. these settings are related to that machine. you can set the memory from there. and in the processors panel you can check if HW Virtualization is enabled by vmware.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the HW Virtulization in Bios, I was completely convinced I had set this to enable long ago, just rechecked now and it was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak from experience with VMware. I only use Virtualbox. The memory setting is for the VM. You should be able to see this in the XP system settings. More than 4GB is useless I guess.

I wonder what the core setting will do. You use 2 now, of how many? What happens if you set this to 1 or higher? I think this is the biggest change with your previous setup.

Comment: I'll test with 1 CPU / 1 Core and report back, I just looked at it like a Computer More cores = Faster computing. (obviously this isnt all true, just the basics)

Comment: Well that is the way it works, but if the host suffers, it may backfire.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware allocation, including memory, are resources you assign to the virtual machine. These resources become available to the VM when it is active and revert back to the host when the VM is down. The exception to this come when you allocated fixed HDD space (as opposed to dynamic). Unless someone knows otherwise I have used VMWare Player, Workstation and Virtualbox and this resource allocation is standard.

In your specific example a 4GB memory allocation against a Windows XP system should be plenty to run most standard games on that OS. If, as you suggest, you are running from a USB drive you will see a performance hit.

You didn't mention if it runs slow specifically when you run games and what graphical options you are running. You can check your system performance in task manager if you really want to inspect this deeper.

Comment: Running slow, in general.
Opening application, Installing are the two main noticeable places where I see the slowdown. The VM HDSK is located on a USB 3.0 Drive, I assume this is my problem?

Comment: @HyeVltg3 | The USB will give you some slowdown. The extent to which this is the problem would be difficult to say. If you can run this from your HDD it would speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Newest update of Avast causes that problem also. To solve , disable hardware assisted virtualization at Settings / Troubleshooting